# Is there a way to "scope to this" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working with Angular 2. The main project folder contains "./src/app" where most of the editing happens.

It is a bit cumbersome to always navigate down to this folder (after collapsing the folder structure, which happens often.).

Is there a way to "Scope to This" (just as in Visual Studio 2012+ Solution Explorer)?

Comment: You can always open another VS Code window, open the src/app/ folder :D

Comment: @huydq5000: not really - if I do this, I get all sorts of "cannot find module xyz" because of faulty import {} from '' paths. They are relative to "baseUrl" in tsconfig - which the is not recognized by VS Code.

Comment: I see, I mean you have to open 2 windows in parallel. In fact, you can open a terminal to run `ng serve` and open the src/app to edit the files.

Comment: @huydq5000: unfortunately editing is not very comfortable - if VS Code can't load imported modules, intellisense does not work and also everything that is imported is not recognized and therefore underlined with squiggly red lines. Please just try it so you know what I mean. It does not work.

Comment: Why don't you just use Visual Studio instead of that glorified notepad with a dark mode?

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature request for this in the vscode github project:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41860.

But in the mean time you can use this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrisdias.vscode-opennewinstance

The only problem is that you'll have two vscode windows open or a single one and you have to re-open the parent folder.

I found a new plugin that works as expected:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rhalaly.scope-to-this